# Автокорреляции данных

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли строить прогнозную модель, если среди предикторов есть с данные с автокорреляцией (например объем продаж охладительных напитков значительно зависит от сезона). Судя из определения автокорреляции это приводит к завышению тестовых статистик, по которым проверяется качество модели, т.е. создается искусственное улучшение качества модели относительно её действительного уровня точности.

Не могу понять логику - наличие зависимости объемов продаж от сезона это ведь хорошо для прогноза, это позволяет более точно предположить объемы продаж в будущем. Или я не верно рассуждаю? С другой стороны прочел массу информации о плохом влиянии автокорреляции данных на прогноз.

Посоветуйте как понять значимая моя автокорреляция или нет, как избавиться от автокорреляции или минимизировать ее влияние.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автокорреляция данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306589/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Первоначальная формулировка вопроса была там, куда Вы дали ссылку. После он был откорректирован (конкретизирован), но был неактивен, поэтому я его удалил и создал новый, данный вопрос.

Comment: Значит, вы недостаточно хорошо улучшили вопрос, чтобы его переоткрыли. В будущем старайтесь так не делать, повторный вопрос в таких случаях обычно закрывают ещё быстрее, чем первоначальный.

Comment: Ясно, я учту, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу понять фразу : "если среди предикторов есть с данные с автокорреляцией (например объем продаж охладительных напитков значительно зависит от сезона)". Т.е. мало того, что у вас есть значения (например) продаж по месяцам или неделям, так вы еще вводите дополнительную предикторную переменную "сезон" что-ли? Понятно, что номер месяца и сезон - не просто коррелированы, а вообще функционально зависимые переменные. Только вот зачем так делать?

*"Посоветуйте как понять значимая моя автокорреляция или нет"* - для этого подойдет статистический тест определения значимости коэффициента корреляции. Но только опять не пойму, корреляцию чего от чего вы собрались делать? Автокорреляция - это зависимость значений ряда от предыдущих значений этого-же ряда. К предикторным переменным это не имеет никакого отношения.

*как избавиться от автокорреляции или минимизировать ее влияние.* - Если "автокорреляция" здесь употреблено в общеупотребимом смысле, а не так, как вам кажется, то ее убирать смысла нет, так как это один из главных характеристик природы временного ряда, очень важный с точки зрения прогнозирования его значений.

Comment: Я не вводил переменную сезон)
У меня есть столбец 'price', в котором в летние месяцы четко наблюдается рост, а в зимние снижение + связь последующей цены от предыдущей. Это ведь и есть автокорреляция, верно? Согласно определению автокорреляции это свойство (регулярный рост/спад) плохо влияет  - "создается искусственное улучшение качества модели относительно её действительного уровня точности".
Я не могу понять почему так, мне кажется что это должно помогать модели..
Вопрос - можно ли как-то убрать это искусственное улучшение качества модели? Нужно ли что-то делать с автокорреляцией или нет?

Comment: Я тоже не могу понять, о чем вы пишете. То, что вы описываете-описание временного ряда с сезонной компонентой. Автокорреляция при этом наблюдается на лагах, равных периоду сезонности. Часто -  при годовой цикличности - на 12-ом лаге. Автокорреляция на малых лагах (1-ом,2-ом) влияют исключительно не трендовую составляющего ряда. Никакого "искусственного улучшения/улучшения" тут нет и быть не может.  А рост-или спад-это естественное свойство вашего ряда. Такие ряды прогнозируют с помощью модели SARIMA. Прочитайте что-нибудь по теории временных рядов -  думаю, многие вопросы отпадут сами.